# How to customize the broker.xml file in the standard Apache ActiveMQ Artemis docker image?

Tags: docker, activemq-artemis

Building a docker image from the artemis-docker package in the official GitHub uses a docker-run.sh that will checks on start-up, if the broker.xml file exists and create a new instance of the broker, in case it does not.

My question: Given, I want to use this image, either self build or by checking out the one from amusara on the official docker hub. How am I supposed to provide a custom broker.xml?

Answer (score 2):

The [official activemq artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.31.1/docker.html#overriding-files-in-etc-folder) as of v2.31.1 recommends the following:

Mount your `broker.xml` from the host system into the following container directory `/var/lib/artemis-instance/etc-override`.

Example:

```bash
docker run \
    --name activemq-artemis \
    -p 61616:61616 \
    -p 8161:8161 \
    -v "${PWD}/broker:/var/lib/artemis-instance/etc-override" \
    --rm \
    apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpin
```

Note that `broker.xml` is placed in a `broker` subfolder in the host system of the current working directory.

You should be able to override other `etc` configuration of the broker:

> The contents of etc-override folder will be copied over to etc folder after the instance creation so that the broker will always start with user-supplied configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The docker-run.sh doesn't create a new instance if the /var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/broker.xml file exists. This means that you need to provide a complete broker instance or to change the broker instance created by the artemis container:

Create a local empty folder with with the artemis user (1001)

```
mkdir broker
chown 1001:1001 broker
```

Create the artemis container with the local empty folder mounted

```
docker run -it --rm --name artemis -e ARTEMIS_USER=admin -e ARTEMIS_PASSWORD=admin -v ${PWD}/broker:/var/lib/artemis-instance  artemis-ubuntu:latest
```

Stop the artemis container

```
docker stop artemis
```

Change artemis instance files

```
ls -al broker
```

Restart the container using the local artemis instance files

```
docker run -it --rm --name artemis -e ARTEMIS_USER=admin -e ARTEMIS_PASSWORD=admin -v ${PWD}/broker:/var/lib/artemis-instance  artemis-ubuntu:latest
```

Docker makes deploying microservice applications very easy but it has some limitations for a production environment. I would take a look to the [ArtemisCloud.io](https://artemiscloud.io/) operator that provide a way to deploy the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Broker on Kubernetes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems legit and probably worked even back when I asked originally. Thankfully, I was apparently not the only one struggling (and not really willing) to build and customize my own images and now there seems to be official docker support.